# Python sqlite3 syntax error with cursor.execute(script, arguments)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have made a sql connector class and I have a select function with a pre-set string and some parameters
but I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x:\User Projects\Python.Password.DataBase\in_testing_modules\sqlconnector.py", line 81, in execute
    self.cursor.execute(script, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

The class simplified

```
import sqlite3 # not sure if I need show this

class SqlConnector:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connection = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect(self, database):
        try:
            with sqlite3.connect(database) as db:
                self.connection = db
                self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        except (TypeError, Exception) as e:
            logging.exception(msg=e)

    def execute(self, script: str = "", parameters: tuple = None):
        try:
            if parameters:
                self.cursor.execute(script, parameters)
            else:
                self.cursor.execute(script)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, sqlite3.OperationalError, Exception) as e:
            logging.exception(msg=e)

    def select(self, selection: str = "*", table: str = "Table", where: list | tuple = None):
        self.execute(
            script="SELECT ? FROM ?", parameters=(selection, table,))
```

Replication of error

```
    sql = SqlConnector()
    sql.connect(":memory:")

    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(Account TEXT NOT NULL)""")
    acc = Account(username="SUPERMAN", password="Secure4321") # Account is a separate class
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO test (Account) VALUES(?)", (acc,))
    sql.commit()

    sql.select(selection="*", table="test")
    retur = sql.fetchall()
    print(retur)
```

*If something about the post is missing please tell me*

Comment: You need to show an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the full error trace message.

Comment: Hope you see that once your invested efforts in preparing your question it is more likely to get actual advice. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CANNOT use parameter binding in place of database object identifiers, such as column and table names. You can only do `SELECT bla FROM qqq WHERE bla = ?`. You cannot replace `bla` or `qqq` here with `?`.

Comment: I've seen you should not format a string when calling the execute function, do to sql injection attacks. Should formatting the string before hand be fine?

Comment: You can use Python string interpolation, of course, as long as you replace all identifier placeholders with actual values before passing the query to the sqlite3 module. BTW, you definitely must import sqlite3 before using it.